# " Unable to find manifest output" after update to 3.1.0-alpha08(canary-8) with robolectric 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

After update 3.1.0-alpha08(canary-8) with robolectric 3.6.1

> Unable to find manifest output

Before alpha08 everything is ok with robolectric 3.6.1

It could happen when I use multi-modules in the project with different flavors.

Here i.e.

I have project-modules: app, base, core, repository
I have flavors: prod, mock

If I run "./gradlew clean test"

I will get problem at tasks:

:base:generateProdDebugUnitTestConfig
:base:generateProdReleaseUnitTestConfig
:base:generateMockDebugUnitTestConfig
:base:generateMockReleaseUnitTestConfig

> Unable to find manifest output

:core:generateProdDebugUnitTestConfig
:core:generateProdReleaseUnitTestConfig
:core:generateMockDebugUnitTestConfig
:core:generateMockReleaseUnitTestConfig

> Unable to find manifest output

:repository:generateProdDebugUnitTestConfig
:repository:generateProdReleaseUnitTestConfig
:repository:generateMockDebugUnitTestConfig
:repository:generateMockReleaseUnitTestConfig

> Unable to find manifest output

However, :app doesn't have these problems.

(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72082657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been accepted by Google and promised to be fix in gradle-plugin-3.1.0-beta-3

[see](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72082657#comment19)